# Wordpress Genesis Theme: How to exclude posts from the child categories in the current category

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I have a Wordpress website that uses Genesis theme. It has categories and child categories.

Currently, the category page shows the posts which belong to that category and also the posts of the child categories.

How do I exclude the posts from the child categories on the category page?

Answer (score 0):

```
$tax_query[] = [
    'taxonomy' => 'posts',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => ['category_name']
];
```

Comment: add terms to your query